# How can I extract status code digits from curl?

Tags: curl, http

I am writing a plugin and I want to extract a status code from my curl request:

```
curl -I localhost | grep HTTP;
```

Right now I have

```
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  
Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
```

as an output but I need only 302

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Dmitrii you can use some options of curl to do this.

example:

```
ip-10-0-8-8:~ tien$ curl -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}\n" https://example.com
200
```

**-s** means silent or quiet mode. Don't show progress meter or error messages.
**-w** makes curl display information on stdout after a competed transfer.
**-o** wrties output to file instead of stdout.

and **\n** adds a new line

Comment: Thank you very much. This solved my problem.